# MongoDB: Possible to get index of "element"/iteration when using mongosh cursor.forEach()?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I'm used to using ES5 `array.forEach()` in the way of `array.forEach((elem, i) => ...)` so that I can have access to the index.

Doing that same thing on MongoDb's cursor via `cursor.forEach((elem, i) => ...)` doesn't work (which makes sense, as it's not an array).  I do not get an index in this case.

Is there a built-in method of getting the equivalent of "index" when using `cursor.forEach()` ?

[The MongoDB cursor.forEach() docs are pretty sparse here.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)

*Note:  I know I can do `cursor.toArray().forEach()` and get an index in my usual way with that.  I was thinking that would be less performant / an unnecessary step if I can already get an "index"/iteration number directly on the cursor, though.*

```
db.collection.find().forEach((doc, i) => {
  if ((i == 0) || (i % 50 == 0)) {
    console.log(`we are here: ${i}`). // nothing gets logged to console...
  }
})
```

Comment: You can do `.find(...).toArray()` if you'd like. But why are you looking for the index (position) info?

Comment: Thanks, I just added that I am aware of .toArray(), but I thought that might be an extra/unnecessary step, and would be less performant on a large collection I would guess?  It's really just for logging to the console so I could keep track of some things as I'm testing this script, nothing important, but I came across the issue so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Gotcha, the edit is helpful. If this were my script I would just initiate a counter variable (to `0`) ahead of the loop and then increment it during each iteration. Couple extra lines but should achieve the desired result. Said another way, I _think_ the direct answer to your question is "no, there are no index/position numbers associated with cursors in general".

Comment: The counter method is simple and more efficient than using .toArray() just for a position number, good suggestion.  We'll see if anyone else chimes in with anything different about a direct answer to index/position numbers associated with cursors.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achive it by using an extra variable to carry index

```
let i = 0;

db.collection.find().forEach(doc => {
  if ((i == 0) || (i % 50 == 0)) {
    console.log(`we are here: ${i}`)    
  }
  i++;
})
```

this would be optimal as well